# How to import query result from splunkstorm to your app?

Tags: c#, logging, sdk, splunk

You can run query on splunkstorm and you get some specified data formed in a table. I created a project on C# and trying to retrieve data from storm to app.
What I tried: installed SDK, started splunk server. But I can't find a way to connect to my splunkstorm.com account execute queries.
The question is how can I import query result from splunkstorm.com to my app?

Answer (score 1):

My way is to write a small BASH Script witch cll the REST API of SPLUNK and saves the data to an CSV file. Then I take the file an do something interesting (build report, make robustness check, ...). This way look complicated, but in real life it is much easier. Plus, you can test your query independly of your code. This will speed up your development and your debugging. By the way, some SPLUNK SDK Versions, Java SDK too, have nasty bugs.